# Storing dictionary of dictionaries using JSON format in Unity/C#?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, data-structures, c#-4.0

I am new to Unity and C#, most of my experience is in Python.
I need to store some data. For the sake of the discussion, let's imagine it looks like (and no, it does not look like json here, I am simply mentioning the type of data):

```
diff1:
  diffMultiplier: 1,
  color: "green",
diff2:
  diffMultiplier: 2,
  color: "yellow",
```

In Python, an easy way to handle this is to have a dictionary of dictionaries and then use json.load and json.dump. Then you just retrieve what you want with something like:

```
myDiff = "diff1"
color = myDict[myDiff]["color"]
```

But Unity JSON serializers don't seem to support dictionaries and even less dictionaries of dictionaries, even with custom libraries. So the solutions I found online so far would be rather complicated to implement.
On the other hand, it seems to me this should a very common "problem" when doing game development so there has to be a simple solution (although maybe not one using JSON).

The reason why I would prefer to use JSON is because while the consumer is a Unity app, the producer is likely to be Python based. But while JSON would be ideal, I am ok with the Python side having to do some extra work.

None of the solutions I found online provide a convenient way to handle that requirement.

Comment: you're right the default unity json tool is somewhat fussy ... have you tried the newtonsoft one?

Comment: Coming from a Python background, I am weary of external libraries that might not be maintained in the future. But mostly I am thinking/hoping that there is an obvious solution I haven't thought of because it seems like something that would be a common issue.

Comment: well the good news is the newtonsoft is actually quietly available com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json so its not exactly external even though it kinda is you can install it by name using that string and it will appear

Comment: and it takes 1 line to convert from say a dictionary of string,int to a json string :D

Comment: You could use a class object and serialize/deserialize an array of them.  If you need them in a dictionary, you can populate a dictionary after deserializing the objects.

Comment: I found similar solutions for a dictionary. But dictionary of dictionaries? That becomes complicated. Surely there is another solution.

Comment: Yes, I can basically implement json.dump and json.load. Just hoping someone did that first since I think it looks like a common requirement.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft! That's the most straight forward and trivial solution - I don't really understand the concerns about maintenance ... what tells you that some Unity built-in thing is better maintained then anything else? ;) The built-in serializer is [extremely limited](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html). If Newtonsoft for some reason scares you maybe you prefer a [c# built-in Json library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to) instead ;)

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell what your actual needs are since the data you show isn't even JSON at all. Why do you think you need a dictionary?

Comment: I also dont understand the reluctance for the newtonsoft one, its been going for years and shows no signs of wavering

Comment: I did not bother structure the data in JSON format, I did not expect people to be bothered with that...

Answer (score 1):

first of all that wouldn't be a JSON format at all (it looks almost more like YAML).

So if you are flexible regarding the JSON format the most trivial would be simply not using a dictionary at all but a plain list like

```
{
    "diffs" : [
        {
            diffMultiplier: 1,
            color: "green"
        },
        {
            diffMultiplier: 2,
            color: "yellow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The according Unity serializer compatible c# class would simply look like

```
[Serializable]
public class Diff
{
    public int diffMultiplier;
    public string color;
}

[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public List<Diff> diffs;
}
```

and you would access it

```
var json = "{ ... }";
var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);

var myDiffIndex = 0;
var color = root.diffs[0].color;
```

---

Now if you really would want to go a more dictionary-ish way there is the good old [SimpleJson](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON/blob/master/SimpleJSONUnity.cs) (but you guess - yet again another third-party library which isn't maintained anymore - because it doesn't have to, JSON isn't changing)

Here you would do something like e.g.

```
var json = "{ ... }";
var root = JSON.Parse(json);

var myDiffIndex = 0;
var color = root["diffs"][0]["color"].AsString();
```

---

But if you really want to use Dictionaries stick to either [Newtonsoft](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) or use the [c# JsonConvert](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to) and do e.g.

```
{
  "diff1": {
    "diffMultiplier": 2,
    "color": "yellow"
  },
  "diff2": {
    "diffMultiplier": 1,
    "color": "green"
  }
}
```

an then still the inner isn't a dictionary but rather a

```
public class Diff
{
    public int diffMultiplier;
    public string color;
}
```

and then (Newtonsoft)

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Diff>>(json);
var color = dictionary["diff1"].color;
```

or (System.Text.Json)

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{IncludeFields = true};
var dictionary = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Diff>>(json, options);
var color = dictionary["diff1"].color;
```

See [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UeVqbf)

---

Of course - if you really really insist - you could use a dictionary for the inner fields as well. Have in mind though that while Python is a loose-typed language, c# is not!

You would have to stick to `object` and do all the casting yourself hoping the type matches:

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var color = (string)dictionary["diff1"]["color"];
var diffMultiplier = (int)dictionary["diff1"]["diffMultiplier"];
```

or accordingly

```
var dictionary = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
var color = (string)dictionary["diff1"]["color"];
var diffMultiplier = (int)dictionary["diff1"]["diffMultiplier"];
```

See [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/amIarC)